# MySQL provides wrong ID after Insert (datatype?)

Tags: python, mysql, sqldatatypes

I have a little python (3.64) script that inserts records in MySQL DB (10.1.26 MariaDB)

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
...
for id in allids
  ...
  cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO entity(id,name) VALUES (%s, %s)", (identifier, name))
```

identifier is an integer like `2832718610241077149` and always 19 digits. 
MySQL field is `int(25)`.

I use to loop the insert statement but i only get 1 record selected (checked with MySQL Workbench). The id there has nothing in common with the identifier in Python, it's something like `2157483647`.

I found out, it works well when i change the DB field to `varchar(25)`. Then all made inserts of the loop can be selected and the IDs are correct too. But i guess it's not how to do it.

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the correct method to grab the last ID? It looks to me like you're fetching the cursor ID, not the last_insert_id.

Comment: Yes i use SELECT * FROM entity in MySQL workbench, not in python. The column id shows not the identifier from my python script and there is only one record (as if stopped after first insert?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, `INT(25)` only indicates the display width, [as explained here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html). You don't get an integer-type field with the capacity to store 25-digit wide numbers, an INT field will always be [32 bits wide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) which explains the results you are getting - the number just gets chopped to fit into 32 bits.

If you need to store such big numbers, have a look at the [DECIMAL or NUMERIC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) types.

Also read [this part of the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html) to understand how MySQL will handle this kind of situations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's it. I changed the field to DECIMAL(25,0) and it works perfect now!